# Javascript: Load an HTML page with button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `button` defined in HTML.

I want to load a page background.html when this button is clicked. But I want to do it from javascript, not from inside the .html file. So on my `register.js` file I have below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnApply").click(function() {
    window.open("background.html");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btnApply" value="Register">
```

But this doesn't load the page. What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean with *load a page*?

Comment: The code works for me as posted in Firefox and Chrome. Clicking the button opens a new tab with the url supplied (a new tab is the usual behavior for a single parameter call to `window.open`). Make sure `background.html` is in the same folder as the page with the button. Please update the question with more details (e,g, what you expected, what you got) if you still have trouble.

Comment: Use Ajax to get content and load on a page where you want. The other way is to route the page with a button click. If you want to load content or a page on a button click without page load use Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because popups are blocked on that page. All you need is to allow them (a screenshot from Chrome):

[image]

And ensure that you:

1. Run this code in the browser (otherwise you will not have `window` object)
2. `background.html` is in the same folder as your script

Comment: This `window.open("background.html");` is totally correct, the OP doesn't need the `./` before the HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

`<input type = "button" id = "btnApply" value = "Register" onclick="loadPage()">`

then  the function could be in your register.js file as :

```
    function loadPage()
{

     window.location="background.html";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `open()` method opens a new browser window. If you want it to load from the same window use `location` object.

```
window.location.assign("background.html");
```